# Comma not inside a backquote

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I have been following `http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/` .
In the chapter `http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/practical-building-a-unit-test-framework.html` there is a macro called `check` which has following definition.

```
(defmacro check (form)
  `(report-result ,form ',form))
```

From my understanding of macro I though above code is equivalent to following code

```
(defmacro check (form)
  `(report-result ,form form))
```

But it throws `Comma not inside a backquote.`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you imagine that `form` is evaluated to the symbol `test`, then this is true:

```
`(report-result ,form ',form))
==> (report-result test 'test)
```

So the `'` is left in the expansion so that in the evaluation the replaced form is quoted. However your "equivalent" does this:

```
`(report-result ,form form)
==> (report-result test form)
```

Here you see that `form` is never replaced so now you need to have a variable named `form` or else you'll get an error.